# Need advice on how to abstract my simulator for opening collectible card packs

Tags: r, function, simulator, montecarlo

I've been building simulators in Excel with VBA to understand the distribution of outcomes a player may experience as they open up collectible card packs. These were largely built with nested for loops, and as you can imagine...were slow as molasses.

I've been spinning up on R over the last couple months, and have come up with a function that handles a particular definition of a pack (i.e., two cards with particular drop rates for n characters on either card), and now am trying to abstract my function so that it can take any number of cards of whatever type of thing you want to throw at it(i.e., currency, gear, materials, etc).

What this simulator is basically doing is saying "I want to watch 10,000 people open up 250 packs of 2 cards" and then I perform some analysis after the results are generated to ask questions like "How many $ will you need to spend to acquire character x?" or "What's the distribution of outcomes for getting x, y or z pieces of a character?"

Here's my generic function and then I'll provide some inputs that the function operates on:

```
mySimAnyCard <- function(observations, packs, lookup, droptable, cardNum){

obvs <- rep(1:observations, each = packs)
pks <- rep(1:packs, times = observations)
crd <- rep(cardNum, length.out = length(obvs))

if("prob" %in% colnames(lookup))
    {
        awrd = sample(lookup[,"award"], length(obvs), replace = TRUE, prob = lookup[,"prob"])
    } else {

        awrd = sample(unique(lookup[,"award"]), length(obvs), replace = TRUE)
    }

qty = sample(droptable[,"qty"], length(obvs), prob = droptable[,"prob"], replace = TRUE)

df <- data.frame(observation = obvs, pack = pks, card = cardNum, award = awrd, quantity = qty)
```

`observations` and `packs` are set to an integer.

`lookup` takes a dataframe:

```
   award  prob
1   Nick  0.5
2   Alex  0.4
3    Sam  0.1
```

and `droptable` takes a similar dataframe :

```
    qty   prob
1   10 0.1355
2   12 0.3500
3   15 0.2500
4   20 0.1500
5   25 0.1000
6   50 0.0080
... continued
```

`cardnum` also takes an integer.

It's fine to run this multiple times and assign the output to a variable and then rbind and order, but what I'd really like to do is feed a master function a dataframe that contains which cards it needs to provision and which lookup and droptables it should pull against for each card a la:

```
  card      lookup       droptable
1    1       char1       chardrops
2    2       char1       chardrops
3    3       char2            <NA>
4    4     credits            <NA>
5    5     credits     creditdrops
6    6 abilityMats abilityMatDrops
7    7 abilityMats abilityMatDrops
```

It's probably never going to be more than 20 cards...so I'm willing to take the speed of a for loop, but I'm curious how the SO community would approach this problem.

Here's what I put together thus far:

```
mySimAllCards <- function(observations, packs, cards){

    full <- data.frame()

    for(i in i:length(cards$card)){

        tmp <- mySimAnyCard(observations, packs, cards[i,2], cards[i,3], i)
        full <- rbind(full, tmp)

    }
}
```

which trips over

```
 Error in `[.default`(lookup, , "award") : incorrect number of dimensions
```

I can work through the issues above, but is there a better approach to consider?

Comment: The general approach seems reasonable. Personally, I would tweak the mySimAnyCard function (and definitely get rid of the assign). Look into 'expand.grid'. As for mySimAllCards, it is very inefficient to use `rbind` in this way. You'd better generate a list of data.frames and then rbind them in one step using `do.call(rbind,ListName)`. Also, I don't see how you are going to deal with <NA> droptables

Comment: use apply instead of a for loop

Comment: @MaratTalipov I removed the assign step as it wasn't doing anything in this context.

Comment: @MaratTalipov, thinking about your comment about the <NA> for droptables...I'll just have the credits lookup have 1 option of "credits" with a prob = 1, and take the values I previously had in credits and move them into a creditsdrops.

Comment: Combining both ideas from @MaratTalipov and @B Williams, could you

1. create a list of data.frames with necessary dimensions and some value to replace
2. use apply to run mySimAnyCard on each data.frame within the list
3. do.call(rbind,ListName)